# How can I make the alpha in a layer proportional to the darkness?

Tags: gimp

I have a layer that I want to merge and I want the dark colors in the layer to have more weight. How can I make it so that black pixels are 100% opacity, white pixels are 0%, and #7F7F7F pixels are 50%? I tried adjusting color curves, but that doesn't seem to be what I want.

Comment: Do you only want white, black and any gray to become transparent, or any color corresponding to its darkness?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Any color, corresponding to its darkness.

Comment: Ah, good. Thought my answer would be totally off when I reread you question and realized the achromatic examples.

Comment: So, did one of the answers help to solve the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short:

I'd decompose the image two times, once into RGBA and once into HSV or HSL, with the Decompose filter: http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-decompose-registered.html

Then, I'd do a RGBA compose with the RGB components taken from the first, and the V or L component (inverted prior to the compose, probably) of the second decompose for the A component: http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-compose.html

Comment: The general idea is ok. Probably you need to simplify it just adding the same image as grayscale and use it as an alpha mask to the original colour one.

Comment: This can work out to be the same, with a few minor differences (mostly about how you get there). 

My goal was to point out that there is something resembling darkness (or lightness) that can be used there - and in that regard, my answer should rather be expanded, because it just assumes that everyone knows what RGBA and HSV/HSL are - and something like the latter would also be part of a "grayscale copy to layer mask" approach, because there are different ways to convert an image or layer to greyscale.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to add transparency in Gimp is to convert a color to alpha by choosing *Layer > Transparency > Color to Alpha*.

In your example choosing white as the color to convert to alpha (i.e. is fully transparent) will lead to the desired result making black 100% opaque, white 0 % opaque (i.e. transparent), and giving all shades of grey a corresponding semi-transparency:

[image]